# How are phase values able to capture motion from video?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, phase

I know that the phase spectrum contains most of the structural information about the image
[importance of phase](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/5/31301/01456290.pdf?arnumber=1456290&ei=g-yhU77QMcq9uAS594C4Dg&usg=AFQjCNFn2y9YtbbhQTDF3qDQvFi3P71HyA&sig2=WgPIBUhEGv2UJie2rEDQ-Q&bvm=bv.69137298,d.c2E). But I want to know more about importance of phase spectrum related to video signals.

I have read that temporal variations of phase values are able to capture most of the dynamical characteristics of the video sequence like global motion in the video [phase based modelling](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://vision.ai.illinois.edu/publications/iccv2007_bghanem_ahuja_dynamictexture.pdf&ei=pe6hU_7LGdG6uASf-YCYBw&usg=AFQjCNHSM76jvsVZoUpFKWdjZ-iCygp8LA&sig2=sFo0Ri5e-t4I0SiRmfdkyQ&bvm=bv.69137298,d.c2E), but I don't understand how it does?

Please consider any real time example say video of rotating wheel or wave (or video of traffic on road) if I compute its phase spectrum using Fourier Transform, the phase values captures motion of rotating wheel (or complex motion of moving car on road), but I don't understand how it does? By which property of Fourier transform could anybody can explain it to me?

Also can anybody explain the mathematical relation between motion and phase? Please correct  if I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you move an impulse in the spatial domain (perhaps representing a pixel on some object in a scene), the unwrapped phase of all the spectra associated with that point will be rotated in the frequency domain by an amount proportional to the distance of the move and the frequency.

Comment: sir, thanks for your feedback but if u explain it in detail related to any example given in my question,i will understand it correctly .